# Advanced Custom Fields error after reinstalling it

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields, elementor

In my Wordpress I use Elementor and Elementor Pro. Also used AFC (Advanced Custom Fields plugin). I accidentally deleted it, but then immediately reinstalled it.But I remember exactly that the old version was installed (an update was available). Now in image src (which use AFC) I see this `<div class="foto_small current_foto" data-img="<br /> <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'sizes' in <b>/var/www/u0723445/data/fispars.ru/wp-content/themes/fispars21/parts/product-gallery.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'product_small' in <b>/var/www/u0723445/data/fispars.ru/wp-content/themes/fispars21/parts/product-gallery.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br /> 4"> <img src="<br /> <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'sizes' in <b>/var/www/u0723445/data/fispars.ru/wp-content/themes/fispars21/parts/product-gallery.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br /> <br /> <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'product_small' in <b>/var/www/u0723445/data/fispars.ru/wp-content/themes/fispars21/parts/product-gallery.php</b> on line <b>20</b><br /> 4" alt=""> </div>`

**So here is file with error after reinstalling**

```
<?php $templateRoot = get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
<div class="hit">
    <div class="foto_big">
        <img id="productImage" class="foto_big_img product__photo--main" src="<?= $images[0]['sizes']['product_small'] ?>" alt=""/>
    </div>
<div class="fotos_small">
<?php 

    $i = 1; 

    foreach( $images as $image ):
        
    if ($i > 5) {
        break;    
    } ?>

    <div class="foto_small" data-img="<?= $image['sizes']['product_small'] ?>">
        <img src="<?= $image['sizes']['product_small'] ?>" alt=""/>
    </div>

<?php 
$i++; 
endforeach; ?>
</div>                            
</div>
<?php if ( !empty($video) ): ?>
<a class="abs-play" data-fancybox href="<?= $video ?>">
    <img src="<?= $templateRoot ?>/img/play.png" alt=""/>
    <p>video</p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</a>
```

**In Console also an error**: (index):455 Uncaught ReferenceError: cart is not defined
at (index):455:39

Comment: Is your acf field set to return an array or the url, because it looks like it is returning a string, and you are trying to access an array. - You can check that in the acf field group

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue.
For me this issue arise, when I had updated the PHP version into 8.X.
I have temporary solution please use below code snippet into your function file.

```
add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta', function ( $image_meta ) {
if ( ! empty( $image_meta['sizes'] ) ) {
    foreach ( $image_meta['sizes'] as $size_key => $size ) {
        if ( ! is_array( $size ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( absint( $size['width'] ) !== $size['width'] ) {
            $image_meta['sizes'][ $size_key ]['width'] = (int) $size['width'];
        }

        if ( absint( $size['height'] ) !== $size['height'] ) {
            $image_meta['sizes'][ $size_key ]['height'] = (int) $size['height'];
        }
    }
}

return $image_meta;
} );
```

This might help you to fix your issue.

I hope this issue soon fixed by Elementor.

Comment: if I just rollback in older php version? And could you say in what way should I use this function. I don't even know php)

Comment: if I use like this: **$images=add_filter( 'wp_calculate_image_srcset_meta', $images)** it doesn't work

Comment: Yes If you rollback to PHP version 7.4 it will work.